# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Am trying make simple app load data from mysql to android using json.
This is my php code:

```
$response = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Demo LIMIT 2");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($response, new Image(
        $row["id"],
        $row["name"],
        $row["image"]
    ));
    }
echo json_encode($response);
}

class Image
{
 var $id;
    var $name;
    var $link1;

function Image($id, $name, $link1)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->link1 = $link1;
}
}
```

result json:

> [{"id":"1","name":"thisisname","link1":"thisislink"},{"id":"2","name":"thisisname","link1":"thisislink"}]

This is android code:

```
class getDetailProduct extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/demo/display.php");

        String kq = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            kq = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return kq;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.e("result", s);
        try {
            JSONArray jsarr = new JSONArray(s); // Error this line
            if(jsarr.length()>0){
                for (int i = 0; i<jsarr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jo = jsarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    imageArrayList.add(new MyImage(
                            jo.getInt("id"),
                            jo.getString("name"),
                            jo.getString("link1")
                    ));
                }
                MyGridViewAdapter myGridViewAdapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_gridview, imageArrayList);
                gridView.setAdapter(myGridViewAdapter);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Logcat:

```
    20:22:57.055 12905-12905/com.example.chientran.demoproject E/result: [{"id":"1","name":"thisisname","link1":"thisislink"},{"id":"2","name":"thisisname","link1":"thisislink"}]
 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
W/System.err:     at com.example.chientran.demoproject.MainActivity$getDetailProduct.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:93)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.chientran.demoproject.MainActivity$getDetailProduct.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:57)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

But if I use hardjson, it work

```
String ss= "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"thisisname\",\"link1\":\"thisislink\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"thisisname\",\"link1\":\"thisislink\"}]";
JSONArray jsonarr  = new JSONArray(ss);// It work
```

`

Comment: Hi, onPostExecute, I have result json from php. So i think `kq` not empty.

Comment: If   Log.e("result", s) is showing the response you posted above then,I don't think anything is wrong with your code except in the  jo.getInt("id") part. Your id is in form of string not int. Check if the log is showing the result.

Comment: @NishanKhadka `jo.getInt("id")` because in model `MyImage(int id, String name, String link)`.

Comment: Okay the error shows that your ID is a String and not an integer , wrap it using Integer.ParseInt();

Comment: I try but not working. I think problem in string result php, because if I use hard string json (coppy result php) it work perfect

Comment: put the same JSON that you have highlighted as a block, in string and try if it works.. If it works that way then there is no problem with the result, also  check kif the JSON format is correct.You can check them in https://jsonblob.com/

Comment: `String ss= "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"thisisname\",\"link1\":\"thisislink\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"thisisname\",\"link1\":\"thisislink\"}]";
JSONArray jsonarr  = new JSONArray(ss);// It work` android auto add \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all for your support. I have resolve my problem.
my android code is correct, but in file php I was used Encode in UTF-8-BOM. So i changed it to Encode in UTF-8. It work

Answer (score 0):

```
       JSONArray arrayresult = ss.getJSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayresult.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject a = arrayresult.getJSONObject(i);

                        YourModel model = new YourModel();
                        model.id = a.getInt("id"),
                        model.name = a.getString("name"),
                        model.link1 = a.getString("link1")

                        modellist.add(model);
                 }
```

Comment: What is `jsonObj` @Edson Reis

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake

Comment: In my code, `ss` and `respone` are same. It's result from php

Answer (score 0):

Okay , this will be your JSON:

```
[
    {"id":"1",
    "name":"thisisname",
    "link1":"thisislink"
    },
    {"id":"2",
    "name":"thisisname",
    "link1":"thisislink"
    }
    ]
```

You should be getting above JSON in your result String.
Now, to process the JSON:

```
try{
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(ss);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
JSONObject jObj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
int id=Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("id"));
String name=jObj.getString("name");
String link1=jObj.getString("link1");
 imageArrayList.add(new MyImage(
                            id,name,link1));
}

}catch(JSONException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this should work